# Rspec testing in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

I have a Queues controller and and QueueItems controller in my rails
application. In routes I have defined as below
`match 'queues/:queue_id/next', :to=> 'queueitems#next'`
In my QueueItems Controller I have a next action and it assigns an
instance variable.

```
def next
@queue = "Regular"
#other stuffs related to regular
end
```

How do I test this in Rspec. I am pretty very new to Rspec. Please help.
I tried like the below

```
describe QueuesController do
    describe "next " do
      it "routes /queues/:queue_id/next" do
        { :get => "/queues/regular_queue/next" }.should route_to(
          :controller => "queue_items",
          :action => "next",
          :queue_id => "regular_queue",
          :format => "json"
            )
        assigns(:queue).should_not be_nil
        expect(response).to be_success
      end
end
```

But it is not at all coming inside my next action in controller.

**Update #2**
**spec/controllers/queue_items_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe QueueItemsController do
        describe 'GET next' do
        it 'assigns @queue' do
          get :next, format: :json
          expect(assigns[:queue]).to eq('regular')
      end
    end
  end
```

**queue_items_controller.rb**

```
def next
   puts "Inside next action..."
    @queue = "regular"

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
  get '/queues/:queue_id/next', :to => 'queue_items#next', :format=>'json'
```

**rake routes**

```
GET  /queues/:queue_id/next(.:format)                                                        queue_items#next {:format=>"json"}
                  /queues/:queue_id/delete(.:format)                                                      queue_items#delete {:method=>:delete, :format=>"json"}
                  /queues/:queue_id/clear(.:format)                                                       queue_items#clear {:format=>"json"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all change `match` to `get` or `post` - it is better to use exactly verb. Let's say it is `get`.

Action `next` is in `QueueItemsController` so test should be in this `queue_items_controller_spec.rb` file (and in folder `spec/controlers`).

and test might be similar to

```
describe QueueItemsController do
  describe "GET next " do

    it "responses json" do
      get :next, format: :json
      expect(response).to be_success
    end

    it "does not response html" do
      get :next, format: :html
      expect(response).not_to be_success # or define more exactly response
    end

    it 'assigns @queue' do
      get :next, format: :json
      expect(assigns[:queue]).to eq('Regular')
    end

  end
end
```

if you would like to test your routes you should follow this articles:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-14/docs/routing-specs
https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/routing-specs/route-to-matcher

Comment: I tried with the above code. But since the routes file defines get 'queues/:queue_id/next', :to=> 'queueitems#next, it is not making the request to controller method. But the test passes. I think again it is checking routing

Comment: what do you mean `it is not making the request to controller method`? Tets send real requests to `QueueItemsController#next`. Would you like to test route matching as well?

Comment: The above tests are not making real requests to QueueItemsController#next. I tried to print some string inside the next method in my controller.. But when I run the specs I should get see that string in the console right? If it is printing in the console, then it means it is making request to controller next action. Is my understanding correct.? I am sorry to say that I am very new to Rspec.

Comment: The error I am getting is as below. Failure/Error: get :next, format: :json
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:format=>:json, :controller=>"queue_items", :action=>"next"}

Comment: As I understand tests are passed so 1. (about real requests) you can check it changing `@queue = "FooBar"` - test should be failed. 2 (about printing some text in controller) try `puts "Action Next is started"` - this should be in rspec output 3. (about error) I need more info: what is test code and where it is placed (what is file), what is you routes (especially `rake routes | grep queue_items`)

Comment: Hi, I have updated my code in my original post as Update#2.. Please let me know if you need more info. I appreciate your effort...

Comment: I see. Please say do 1st (about real requests) and 2nd (about printing some text in controller) in my previous comment work or not? Other words does the test fail if change in controller `@queue = "FooBar"` and do you see `"Inside next action..."` in rspec output? And where do you have error `ActionController::RoutingError` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51559/discussion-between-rubyist-and-gotva)